# Converting JSON to XML using XSLT without XML tag in JSON file

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I need your help in converting JSON format into XML format using XSLT.

**My JSON**

```
{
    "SARIETransferRq": {
    "SARIETransferRqHeader": {
    "CorporateID": "ABCD0001",
    "CorpReferenceNumber": "4716936"
},
    "SARIETransferRqBody": {
    "AccountNumber": "02020202020",
    "DebitCurrency": "SAR",
    "Instructions2": "luaba",
    "Instructions3": "fadjiugu",
    "Instructions4": "rifdij",
    "Description": "sample description for service fee",
    "AMLPurposeCode": "BB"
}
},
  "Signature": {
    "SignatureValue": "sample"
  }
  }
```

**Output XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <root>
 <SARIETransferRq>
  <SARIETransferRqHeader>
  <CorporateID>ABCD0001</CorporateID>
  <CorpReferenceNumber>4716936</CorpReferenceNumber>
  </SARIETransferRqHeader>
   <SARIETransferRqBody>
  <AccountNumber>02020202020</AccountNumber>
  <DebitCurrency>SAR</DebitCurrency>
  <Instructions2>luaba</Instructions2>
  <Instructions3>fadjiugu</Instructions3>
  <Instructions4>rifdij</Instructions4>
  <Description>sample description for service fee</Description>
  <AMLPurposeCode>BB</AMLPurposeCode>
  </SARIETransferRqBody>
  </SARIETransferRq>
  <Signature>
  <SignatureValue>sample</SignatureValue>
  </Signature>
  </root>
```

In most of JSON to XML conversion i see there is xml tag in json file but  my required doesn't have this XML tag in json file.

Can anyone suggest what needs to be corrected here:

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use or can you use? With XSLT 3 (e.g. Altova XML 2017 R3 or later, Saxon 9.8 or later, SaxonJS 2) you can process JSON easily and e.g. use the XPath 3.1 function `json-to-xml` to convert any JSON to the XML format that function delivers and of course further process/transform that result as needed to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming XSLT 3 where you start with a named template and pass in the JSON as a string parameter (you could use a file name/URI to the JSON file as well and make that param then `<xsl:param name="json" select="unparsed-text('input.json')"/>`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml($json)/*"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[@key]">
    <xsl:element name="{@key}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:param name="json" as="xs:string" expand-text="no">
{
    "SARIETransferRq": {
    "SARIETransferRqHeader": {
    "CorporateID": "ABCD0001",
    "CorpReferenceNumber": "4716936"
},
    "SARIETransferRqBody": {
    "AccountNumber": "02020202020",
    "DebitCurrency": "SAR",
    "Instructions2": "luaba",
    "Instructions3": "fadjiugu",
    "Instructions4": "rifdij",
    "Description": "sample description for service fee",
    "AMLPurposeCode": "BB"
}
},
  "Signature": {
    "SignatureValue": "sample"
  }
  }
  </xsl:param>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Online sample with SaxonJS](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22xml%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Croot%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22json-to-xml%28%24json%29%2F*%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Froot%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22*%5B%40key%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aelement%20name%3D%22%7B%40key%7D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aelement%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22json%22%20as%3D%22xs%3Astring%22%20expand-text%3D%22no%22%3E%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22SARIETransferRq%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22SARIETransferRqHeader%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22CorporateID%22%3A%20%22ABCD0001%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22CorpReferenceNumber%22%3A%20%224716936%22%0D%0A%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22SARIETransferRqBody%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22AccountNumber%22%3A%20%2202020202020%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22DebitCurrency%22%3A%20%22SAR%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22Instructions2%22%3A%20%22luaba%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22Instructions3%22%3A%20%22fadjiugu%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22Instructions4%22%3A%20%22rifdij%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22Description%22%3A%20%22sample%20description%20for%20service%20fee%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22AMLPurposeCode%22%3A%20%22BB%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22Signature%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22SignatureValue%22%3A%20%22sample%22%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aparam%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=&input-type=None).

Comment: We will get a file with just json format, so i need either to add xml tags like <sample> json content </sample> using xslt and then convert to xml or
if there is option directly to convert json content to xml using xslt.

Comment: XSLT 2 and 3 allow you to start the processing with a named template of the XSLT stylesheet, in the case of XSLT 3 this defaults to the one named `xsl:initial-template`. Any non XML sources (like your JSON) can be passed in as parameters and be processed. So above code is an XSLT 3 stylesheet you are supposed to run with the default named template, not providing any XML input. The sample, for self-containedness, makes the JSON data a string parameter. but as already explained, you could as well use `<xsl:param name="json" select="unparsed-text('input.json')"/>` to read from a JSON file.

Comment: Thanks Martin.
We don't have capability to pass json file.
Can we add xml tag to json content using xslt?
<sample> json content </sample>

Comment: @VaraprasadBolisetty, I don't know what your "we" refers to but if you don't know how to pass a JSON file name or URL to XSLT, whether it is for a complete JSON to pure XML conversion or just to wrap JSON into an XML element, I don't see how you want to use XSLT. Perhaps try a different tool set.

Comment: Hi Martin, 
We are using XML version="1.0".

Is there any way to achieve above requirement?

Comment: The key is to use XSLT 3, there are various implementations, Saxon (exists as Saxon Java in HE, PE and EE editions, as Saxon.NET for MS .NET framework in HE, PE, EE editions, as SaxonC, as SaxonJS for the browser and for Node.js), or XMLSpy or XML Raptor from Altova. There are also various proprietary extensions to XSLT 1 or 2 to process JSON, it all depends on your environment/tool set. You haven't provided any information about that. And of course there are other tools to process JSON.